# java.io.FileNotFoundException: <my path> (The system cannot find the file specified). Please guide

Tags: java

Following is the code that throws the exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\cloud project\Resource freeing attacks in cloud performance code and db\Ftp\Ftp\src\public.key (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I am not able to figure out why the key file is not found. I doubt the key files are not getting written which is why the system does not find them.

```
package com.util;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class SimpleFTPClient {
public static String path = "C:/cloud project/Resource freeing attacks in cloud performance code and db/Ftp/Ftp/src/";

private URLConnection m_client;
private String host;
private String user;
private String password;
private String remoteFile;
private String erMesg;
private String succMesg;

public SimpleFTPClient() {
}
public void setHost(String host) {
    this.host = host;
}
public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}
public void setPassword(String p) {
    this.password = p;
}

public void setRemoteFile(String d) {
    this.remoteFile = d;
}
public synchronized String getLastSuccessMessage() {
    if (succMesg == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return succMesg;
}
public synchronized String getLastErrorMessage() {
    if (erMesg == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return erMesg;
}
public synchronized boolean uploadFile(InputStream is) {
try {

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        OutputStream os = m_client.getOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
        String algo = "RSA/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
        SimpleFTPClient sftpcx = new SimpleFTPClient();
        KeyPair kpr = sftpcx.LoadKeyPair(path, algo);
        PublicKey pubkey = kpr.getPublic();
        Cipher encrypt =  Cipher.getInstance(algo);  
        encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubkey);  
        CipherOutputStream cout=new CipherOutputStream(bos, encrypt);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int readCount;

        while ((readCount = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            cout.write(buffer, 0, readCount);//cout instead of bos
        }
        cout.close();
        bis.close();
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();

        this.succMesg = "Uploaded!";

        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        StringWriter sw0 = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter p0 = new PrintWriter(sw0, true);
        ex.printStackTrace(p0);
        erMesg = sw0.getBuffer().toString();

        return false;
    }
}
public synchronized boolean downloadFile(String localfilename) {
    try {
        InputStream is = m_client.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>"+localfilename);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(localfilename);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
        String algo = "RSA/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
        SimpleFTPClient sftpc = new SimpleFTPClient();
        KeyPair kpr = sftpc.LoadKeyPair(path, algo);
        PrivateKey prvkey = kpr.getPrivate();
        Cipher decrypt =  Cipher.getInstance(algo);  
        decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, prvkey);  
        CipherInputStream cin=new CipherInputStream(bis, decrypt);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int readCount;
        while ((readCount = cin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
        }
        cin.close();
        bis.close();
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        this.succMesg = "Downloaded!";

        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        StringWriter sw0 = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter p0 = new PrintWriter(sw0, true);
        ex.printStackTrace(p0);
        erMesg = sw0.getBuffer().toString();

        return false;
    }
}

public synchronized boolean connect() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("ftp://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + host + "/" + remoteFile + ";type=i");
        m_client = url.openConnection();
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.."+"ftp://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + host + "/" + remoteFile + ";type=i");
        return true;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        StringWriter sw0 = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter p0 = new PrintWriter(sw0, true);
        ex.printStackTrace(p0);
        erMesg = sw0.getBuffer().toString();
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String arg[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    SimpleFTPClient f = new SimpleFTPClient();
    f.setHost("ftp.drivehq.com");
    f.setUser("sabari06");
    f.setPassword("sabari06");
    f.setRemoteFile("c.txt");
    boolean connected = f.connect();
    try{
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyGen.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair generatedKeyPair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
    System.out.println("Generated Key Pair");
        f.dumpKeyPair(generatedKeyPair);
    f.SaveKeyPair(path, generatedKeyPair);
    KeyPair loadedKeyPair = f.LoadKeyPair(path, "RSA");
        System.out.println("Loaded Key Pair");
    f.dumpKeyPair(loadedKeyPair);
    }catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return;
}
}
private void dumpKeyPair(KeyPair keyPair) {
    PublicKey pub = keyPair.getPublic();
    System.out.println("Public Key: " + getHexString(pub.getEncoded()));
    PrivateKey priv = keyPair.getPrivate();
    System.out.println("Private Key: " + getHexString(priv.getEncoded()));
}

private String getHexString(byte[] b) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        result += Integer.toString((b[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
    }
    return result;
}

public void SaveKeyPair(String path, KeyPair keyPair) throws IOException {
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
    PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

    X509EncodedKeySpec x509EncodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(
            publicKey.getEncoded());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + "\\public.key");
    fos.write(x509EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded());
    fos.close();

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
            privateKey.getEncoded());
    fos = new FileOutputStream(path + "\\private.key");
    fos.write(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded());
    fos.close();
}

 public KeyPair LoadKeyPair(String path, String algorithm)
        throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidKeySpecException {

    File filePublicKey = new File(path + "/public.key");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path + "/public.key");
    byte[] encodedPublicKey = new byte[(int) filePublicKey.length()];
    fis.read(encodedPublicKey);
    fis.close();

    File filePrivateKey = new File(path + "/private.key");
    fis = new FileInputStream(path + "/private.key");
    byte[] encodedPrivateKey = new byte[(int) filePrivateKey.length()];
    fis.read(encodedPrivateKey);
    fis.close();

    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
    X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(
            encodedPublicKey);
    PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
            encodedPrivateKey);
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

    return new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey);
}
}
```

Comment: there are spaces in your path

Comment: I have tried with different paths not having spaces as well. e.g. D:/DriveHQDownloads/tmp

Comment: did you check java application permission for writing in the specified path ?

Answer (score 2):

Your path contains spaces, which are not escaped. For a windows machine the path should be something like

`C:\\Users\\Joe\\image.jpg`

As the first step, verify that you can load the file from a folder with no spaces. For example, move the file to `c:\\temp\\public.key`

If that works you will know that there are no ownership problems, or writing permissions.
If that doesn't work then there's something else afoot.

Once you are able to load the file from c:\temp, move the file back to where you want it to be and work on the spaces.
To escape spaces in Windows, use "/". For example. "Program Files" can be referenced as c:\Program/ Files\

Also, remember that you don't always need to reference the file by absolute name, if the file is in the classpath you can load it as a resource:

`InputStream inputStream = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("public.key");`

Finally, try not to use platform dependent separators in the file name. Instead use File.separator, File.separatorChar, or System.getProperty("file.separator").

Comment: Hello Alexandre, the file is actually not already there. The code generates a public key and writes it to the path mentioned. So I doubt the problem is that the file is not getting written.

Comment: Break your problem into smaller steps. Save a file to c:\\temp and try to read it. If that works, then work on your path.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\tmp\public.key (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Did you use c:\ or c:\\ ? One or two backslashes?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Command prompt or your IDE as **Administrator**. You don't have appropriate writing rights as I've judged. Just right click on Command Prompt or the IDE and choose **Run As Administrator** and try executing the program again.

Comment: still the same exception as before even after running the IDE as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have a better error message like the following function below gives.
Alternatively past the path in the Windows Explorer.

Not needed should be bos.flush, close as bos is wrapped.

Already known and confirmed again: Under Windows a forward slash `/` is an old POSIX compatibility feature, so okay. The backslash must be self-escapped as `\\`.

A FileNotFoundException can also be thrown when creating a file. Check also that the file is not locked, maybe by a forgotten `close()`.

Last solution:

```
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

The checking function:

```
/**
 * Throws a FileNotFoundException with the exact spot where the path goes
 * wrong.
 * @param file or directory.
 * @throws FileNotFoundException when not found.
 */
public static void checkFileFound(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    if (file.exists()) {
        File firstWrong = file;
        File dir = file.getParentFile();
        while (dir != null && !dir.exists()) {
            firstWrong = dir;
            dir = dir.getParentFile();
        }
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File/Directory does not exist; '"
                + firstWrong.getPath() + "'; in " + file.getPath());
    }
}
```

---

In `uploadFile` after `try {` :

```
checkFileNotFound(new File(path));
```

or make your own test app:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String path = "C:/cloud project/Resource freeing attacks in cloud performance code and db/Ftp/Ftp/src/";
        checkFileNotFound(new File(path));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: used the \\ still the problem. I am not able to understand the other solutions, sorry.

Comment: Extended the answar with an actual check you should do, to pinpoint the error.